# Sharing items to a particular number of people

Tags: recreational-mathematics

If I have a game where everyone contributes money, but only $n$ ($11$ in this case) people can win. How do I share the winnings such that the prize amounts do not diverge significantly as the amount contributed increases?

If I have winnings a, b , c ... ( a + 10)

I want a/b at \$1000 to be greater than a/b at say $\1 million

Also, if they contribute differing amounts, how do I award them as a function of the contributed amount. So that it depends on their position and amount contributed.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412988/sharing-items-to-a-particular-number-of-people-as-a-funtion-of-amount-contribute

Comment: Are you asking how to express a large natural number as the sum of $n=11$ parts that are "as equal as possible"?

Comment: Théophile has a reasonable solution

Comment: if the winning contributions total \$1000 I give the first person \$300 for example and the second \$200, When the contributions are  \$1 million, I might want it to be maybe 300k, 290k correspondingly

Comment: It seems you have an opinion about how to do this, but it has not been expressed clearly enough in the body of the Question for a solution to be deduced mathematically.

Comment: Maybe as equal as possible, but not equal

Comment: if the winning contributions total \$1000 I give the first person \$300 for example and the second \$200, When the contributions are  \$1 million, I might want it to be maybe \$300k, \$290k correspondingly

Comment: Yes, there would be many ways to do this.  It's not constrained mathematically enough to suggest one way is "best", but if you are distributing the prizes, it can be done by an arithmetic series as Theophile suggests, or in some other fashion where the prize differences are small in relation to the total.

Comment: I've adjusted the question, personally I'll try different methods, then use a graph to see if it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give each winner a *base prize* of $p$ along with a *bonus* according to whether they won first, second, etc., place. For instance:

> 1st place: $p$ + 100
>   2nd place: $p$ + 90
>   $\cdots$
>   11th place: $p$ + 10
>   11th place: $p$ + 0

Say that $M$ dollars have been collected in total. The total prize money is $11p + 550$, so we have $$p = \frac{M-550}{11}.$$

You can probably come up with a more exciting set of bonuses; this is just to show one possible approach.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412988/sharing-items-to-a-particular-number-of-people-as-a-funtion-of-amount-contribute

Comment: absolutely fantastic